# Не открывает нужную страницу capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

Есть тест где происходит переход на разные страницы посредством  capybara-webkit 1.14 и не всегда открываются нужные страницы. 
То есть, например открывется на google.com , затем переход на www.yopmail.com.
В current_url пишет https://www.google.com .
То есть на http://www.ypmail.com перехода не было.
Встречался кто то с такой ситуацией?

Сам тест:

```
Given /^visit google$/ do
  visit 'https://google.com'
end

Given /^Mailers yopmail$/ do
  visit 'http://www.yopmail.com/ru/'
  wait_for_ajax
end

When /^Input email and find link yopmail$/ do
  visit 'http://www.yopmail.com/ru/'
end
```

вот что пишет дебаг:

```
Page finished with true
Load finished
Started "Visit(http://www.yopmail.com/ru/)"
Finished "Visit(http://www.yopmail.com/ru/)" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received 0 from "https://google.com"
Load started
Started request to "https://google.com"
```

env.rb :

```
if ENV['driver'].to_s == "webkit"
  Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
  Capybara.run_server = false
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
  #
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.debug = true
    config.timeout = 20
    config.block_unknown_urls
    config.allow_unknown_urls
    config.ignore_ssl_errors
    config.skip_image_loading
  end
end
```

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Исправлено

Comment: покажите текст теста. добавьте лог выполнения, так как его вы водит тест.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman готово

Comment: То, что вы привели, не тест, а step definitions (определения действий для тестов).

Comment: @D-side Скажите вам суть вопроса ясна?

Comment: @s.borisov нет, не ясна. "Встречался кто то с такой ситуацией?" -- вы не описали ситуацию в достаточной мере, чтобы её воспроизвести. Приведите код именно **теста**, а не того, из каких кусочков он составлен.